# need to add where clause in Rest API Get request in apex

Tags: apex, rest-api, metadata-api, code

/services/data/v39.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id,Name,AccountNumber,Type+FROM+Account+limit+10

i need to add where clause here

LiKE :- **`/services/data/v39.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id,Name,AccountNumber,Type+FROM+Account+where+rating!=warm+limit+10`**

But getting 400 bad request .Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

Your filter condition needs to use quotes around literal strings.

```
/services/data/v39.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id,Name,AccountNumber,Type+FROM+Account+where+rating!='warm'+limit+10
```

Comment: Thanks ,SFDCFOX,

Comment: Thanks ,SFDCFOX,But instead of hardcore value if i want to take one string as this api will be in for loop and value will change for rating,How to add that string in API call..

Comment: like String rating=acc.rating and this string i need to use in my API call

Comment: @sandy That will depend on the code you're using (Apex, JavaScript, etc). The API itself requires these quotes to be present.